# Wordpress attachments in query_posts

Tags: jquery, global-variables, infinite-scroll

Morning,

I need some guidance on some WP code. I'm wondering if it's possible to take this code (which is grabbing all the images from the posts across my site and dumping them out):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => null ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    the_attachment_link($post->ID, true);
    the_excerpt();
}
}
```

and use the `query_posts();` function in WP instead so I could create some pagination for all the images.

Thanks in advance,
R

**UPDATE**

I seem to have got something working with this below, but it's pulling in one post, infinitely.

```
    <?php $ID = get_the_ID();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("order=DESC&orderby=post_date&posts_per_page=8&paged=$paged"); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => null, );
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            the_attachment_link($post->ID, true);
            the_excerpt();
        }
    }
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```